# Sqlcmd can connect to old SQL Server 2005, but connection string pyodbc with Driver 18 from Microsoft does not work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, pyodbc, sqlcmd

I need to connect with a python to an old legacy SQL Server database (2005) from a Windows 11 laptop

I can access the server and login with `sqlcmd`.

The following statement works to connect:

```
sqlcmd -S <IP>,<PORT> -N disable -C -U <UID> -P <PWD>
```

However the connection string does not work via pyodbc

```
DRIVER=ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server;SERVER=10.101.6.197,1433;UID=<UID>;PWD=<PWD>;DATABASE=<DATABASE>;Encrypt=no;
```

I tried all drivers also 13 and 17. Anybody has an idea how to have the equivalent of `sqlcmd` as a connection string.

- Python version 3.12
- Pyodbc: 5.1.0

Different drivers tried.

```
Encrypt=disabled (not recognize)
Trusted_Connection=yes
```

It seems to be a TLS version issue but somehow with connection string I can not completely disable encryption. Everything is behind VPN connections so security wise and the server is only occasional spun up when needed so that disabled encryption is acceptable in this edge case.

Comment: 2005 has no support for "recent" TLS versions, where as Windows 11 only supports 1.2 (out of the box). They literally can't communicate unless you make your Windows 11 environment insecure. TL;DR: get that 2005 instance offline and migrate to a supported version of SQL Server.

Comment: True, however with sclcmd I can give disable the encryption it for that specific connection. using the -N option however my challenge is to do that with the connection string as indeed I have no desire to make the WIndows 11 environment less secure

Comment: Try `Encrypt=no`

Comment: Does Windows 11 still have the ancient "SQL Server" ODBC driver that has shipped with Windows for many years?

Comment: If you're using `sqlcmd -N disable` without errors then I'd assume that you're using the Go version of sqlcmd, which uses its own Go implementation of MS-TDS ([go-mssqldb](https://github.com/microsoft/go-mssqldb)) for protocol support. If you want to use an ODBC Driver for SQL Server to connect to an ancient SQL Server 2005 instance then you'll need to go all the way back to ODBC Driver (11) for SQL Server for compatibility. Ref: [SQL version compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/windows/system-requirements-installation-and-driver-files#sql-version-compatibility)

Comment: I wouldn't normally recommend `pymssql`, but if you need to do this from Python it runs on top of FreeTDS so might have compatibility reaching further back.

Comment: Encrypt=no does not work @Charlieface I tried that. After further investigation it is because PWD / UID are still encyrpted when connecting even though Encrypt=no is used. Hence the version issue on TLS still plays up.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning had tried the old ODBC 11 driver but to no avail. However your suggestion pymssql might work. I try this. I managed to get it working with FreeTDS on an ubuntu machine with python using the FreeTDS as there the Encryption=off parameter can be set.  So I will try the mymssql on windows 11